# How do I specify a different target directory install for source files in Nuget?

Tags: nuget, nuspec

Here's the structure of my web development project:

- Web Project

  - Content
  - My Theme

    - Content

      - Less
      - Scripts
      - etc.

When I install Less Bootstrap Package, it always installs the files in the content directory:

- Web Project

  - Content

    - **bootstrap**
  - My Theme

    - Content

      - Less
      - Scripts
      - etc.

I want it to install the files here:

- Web Project

  - Content

    - **bootstrap**
  - My Theme

    - Content

      - **Less**

        - alerts.less
        - badges.less
        - etc.
      - Scripts
      - etc.

Is there a way to specify the target path for source files?  I haven't seen any documentation on it and the only questions I've seen about this pertain to specifying where the .package files are installed. I have a  difficult time believing that this option doesn't exist, especially considering that developers are very finicky about how they organize their source trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported by NuGet. The location of the files is defined by the NuGet  package and currently cannot be overridden.

There is an [open work item](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1914) where this problem is discussed with proposed solutions but it has not yet been implemented.